# Serving Up Slim/Jade with Rails Assets Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, asset-pipeline, pug, slim-lang

I'm writing an Angular.js app and it needs to grab static HTML files for its various views.

I'd like to use Slim or Jade to write these static pre-compiled views, and serve them up using the Rails assets pipeline.

I'v figured out how to serve html files from the assets pipeline using this in my config/application.rb:
`config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/html"`

As for compiling slim or jade to html, I've searched hi and low for a solution, but the closest I've gotten is [slim_assets](https://github.com/crowdint/slim_assets), but it compiles to JST, not HTML.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used Ruby on Rails before, so I don't know if that is exactly what you need: https://github.com/zohararad/jader

Comment: I think what you are looking for is something like [connect-assets](https://github.com/adunkman/connect-assets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jade with this 
https://github.com/inossidabile/jade

You can use Handlebars with this 
https://github.com/leshill/handlebars_assets